# Failed to install 'plugin.google.maps':Error: Variable(s) missing: API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID in cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

while adding a platform to cordova project `ionic platform add android` in last I got this error,

> Failed to install 'plugin.google.maps':Error: Variable(s) missing:
>   API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID
>       at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:343:23
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:
>   13)
>       at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13) Error: Variable(s) missing: API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID

however I have provided recently created key in google console in `pakage.json`

```
{
      "variables": {
        "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "My Key Here"
      },
      "locator": "cordova-plugin-googlemaps",
      "id": "plugin.google.maps"
    },
```

also replaced the key in index.html at `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=My Key Here"></script>`

why I am getting this?

Comment: Just a comment about facing an issue getting the API to work in Cordova.  I ended up going with Google's JavaScript API vs. the plugin for Cordova and it worked like a charm. I followed this example and it worked like a charm. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="<YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID_AS_FOUND_IN_ADMOB>"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this command may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.